# How to import JSON data in php file into Python

Tags: php, python, json, parsing

Please can anyone get me started with the following question?

I get a php file from a website that contains lots of data but I only need some of it. The file is so large I cannot paste it here.

I want to extract the data which is in `JSON` format and work with it in python.

The file for the example is named `JSON1.php`. When I open it using a text editor the contents are laid out in this format. Though this is a `JSON` example I found online.

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can see it is standard `JSON`.

What I have been able to google and what I have found here doesn't deal with `JSON` data saved in a file with .php extention.

Many thanks!

Comment: It's just a file, Python doesn't care that it's called ".php". The contents are still plain text, so you can just pass the file handle into `json.load()` or the file's contents into `json.loads()`

Comment: this question really has noting to do with php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835672/650884

Answer (score 0):

You can access json from a .php file the same way as a .json file.

Example code:

```
import json

with open("JSON1.php", "rb") as f:
    jsonData = json.loads(f.read())

# Now you can use the json as a python dictionary
```